# Odoo - How to send an email programmatically with the existing odoo email template?

Tags: odoo-12

I want to send an email programmatically with the existing odoo email template.

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you share your effort/attempt code in your question?

Comment: Nothing i have tried because i dont know where to start or how to send email in odoo?

Comment: You can just research over this point over web as there are lots of content is there for sending mail.

Comment: @KevalMehta No, because I want to send an email using an existing email template in odoo.

Comment: Please check this "https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-send-mail-using-template-in-odoo10-124844

Answer (score 6):

Call the `send_mail` method of `template` object with the id of the record to render the template.

```
template_id.send_mail(record_id, force_send=True)
```

`force_send` is used to specify to send the email immediately; otherwise, use the mail queue (recommended).

Comment: What is **record_id** in the given answer?

Comment: It is the record id, used to render the template

Answer (score 1):

A sample code for Odoo 12:

```
template = self.env.ref('<module>.<template_id>')
template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

where `self.id` is the record ID of the model referenced in the template's `model_id` field, which means its data will be used when rendering the template.

Answer (score 0):

```
template_obj = self.env['mail.mail'].search([search your template)]   
template_data['email_from'] = 'xyz@abc.com'
template_data['reply_to'] = 'xyz@abc.com'
template_data['subject'] = 'this is subject'
template_data['body_html'] = 'body'
template_id = template_obj.create(template_data)
template_id.send()
```